For electromagnetic waves in matter, is the electric field also perpendicular to the magnetic field (like in vacuum)?
In vacuum, the Maxwell equations show that the E-Field and the B-Field are always perpendicular to each other and perpendicular to the direction of propagation. However, in matter (a dielectric) it is possible that the E-Field and the direction of propagation are not perpendicular to each other (longitudinal oscillation).
I am wondering whether E- and B-Field are always perpendicular or whether that just applies to electromagnetic waves in vacuum as well.

Another good thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400654/why-are-the-mathbf-e-and-mathbf-b-fields-of-an-electromagnetic-wave-mutual

This question is similar to: Why are the $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ fields of an electromagnetic wave mutually perpendicular?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
